# int cannot be dereferenced error Java

Tags: java, int, compareto

I am getting the error from this line of code:

if(n.getString().compareTo(string) > 0)

getString() is a method of the n object which just returns a String variable.

EDIT:

Complete example:

```
public void add (Node n){
        if(n.getString().compareTo(string) > 0){   //left side
            if(leftChild == null){  //no left child
                setLeft(n);         //put it as the left child
            }
            else{
                getLeft().add(n);    //recursively call add on the left child  
            }
        }
```

Comment: Except that the error would indicate that `n` is an `int`, **not** an object.

Comment: It looks like `n` is an `int`, not an object with a `getString` method.

Comment: can you show your code ? what do you want to do ?

Comment: How do you know that n is an int?

Comment: @PetterFriberg We don't know. It might be `n.getString()` that's an `int`.

Comment: @Brandon We need a complete example, including Node class, in the question not the comments. This is dangerously close to being closed.

Comment: @PaulBoddington I have edited my post, sorry for the confusion

Comment: In that example, the only place that could produce that error is when there is a method `int getString() { .. }`

Comment: The stacktrace will tell you the line where you think you're dealing with an object, but in fact are trying to call a method on an `int`.

Comment: @PaulBoddington thank you Paul, you were correct. After examining my return type for getString() I realized the problem

Comment: Well I'm glad you've solved the problem. Read this before your next question, because otherwise we're basically just guessing. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was another mistake of trying to call a method using a primitive data type. The return type for my getString() method was an int:

```
public String getString() {
    return string;
}
```